# Using PySerial on macOS

Tags: python-3.x, macos-ventura

I want to use pyserial to read data from a serial device with python but I seem to fail at the most basic example.

I installed python with 'brew install python3', installed pyserial as said in the documentation 'python3 -m pip install pyserial' and took the following from the pyserial docs and changed the device:

> import serial
>
> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-130') print(ser.name)
> ser.close()

I ran it with 'sudo python3 serial.py' and got an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/x/serial.py", line 1, in 
> import serial   File "/Users/x/serial.py", line 3, in 
> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-130')
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial' (most likely due to a circular import). Did you mean: 'serial'?

It says the I might have a typo but with serial.serial instead of serial.Serial I just get another error and I cant imagine that their examples are that faulty. I guess its a problem with the python environment?

Comment: After setting up a freebsd with a clean pyton i got the same problem. it seems i doesnt like the file name like the imported module - but doesnt say that to play hard to get.